# How to consume web API Patch from c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi, patch

I need to consume my web API PATCH method from C# code. My controller as follows,

```
[HttpPatch("updateMessageTemplate/{templateId}")]
public IActionResult UpdateMessageTemplate([FromHeader] int clientId, int templateId,[FromBody] string template)
{
    try
    {
        notificationService.UpdateMessageTemplate(clientId,templateId,template);
        return Accepted();
    }
    catch
    {
        return StatusCode(500);
    }
}
```

I just tried C# code as follows to consume my API PATCH method.

```
public string UpdateMessageTemplate(string token, int clientId, int templateID, string template)
{
    try
    {

        string serviceUrl = string.Format("{0}/notification/updateMessageTemplate/{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIURL"], templateID);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("clientId", clientId.ToString());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("bearer {0}", token));
        var response = client.PatchAsync(serviceUrl).Result;
        return response;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        NameValueCollection logParams = new NameValueCollection();
        Logger.LogErrorEvent(ex, logParams);
        throw;
    }
}
```

But above consume method is wrong. can you please tell me what is the correct way to consume it?

Comment: Your API is expecting `{templateId}`, but the url formed does not contains that. Also, to pass `template` you need to pass the body as `StringContent` from client.

Comment: @user1672994 Sorry I missed that `{templateId}` (updated the code) . Can you please give me sample code.how to pass body as string from client

Answer (score 1):

Your code has two issues :

- `string.Format("{0}/notification/updateMessageTemplate", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIURL"], templateID)` is not adding the templateId.
- You are not passing `template` as body to requrest

  ```
  public string UpdateMessageTemplate(string token, int clientId, int templateID, string template)
  {
      try
      {
         string serviceUrl =$"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIURL"]}/notification/updateMessageTemplate/{templateID}";

         HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
         StringContent content = new StringContent(template);
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("clientId", clientId.ToString());
         client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("bearer {0}", token));
         var response = client.PatchAsync(serviceUrl, content).Result;
         return response;

      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         NameValueCollection logParams = new NameValueCollection();
         Logger.LogErrorEvent(ex, logParams);
         throw;
       }
  }
  ```

> If your code is expecting the encoding and media type in body content then use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.stringcontent.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Net_Http_StringContent__ctor_System_String_System_Text_Encoding_System_String_) version of `StringContent`.

The above modified code should fix your issue. Another suggestion - Use aysnc/await chain instead of using `.Result` on async call which can create the deadlock in your code.

Comment: this show me this error . `Error CS1061 'HttpClient' does not contain a definition for 'PatchAsync' and no accessible extension method 'PatchAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpClient' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` This error shows in my previous code too

Comment: first argument as `HttpClient`? See the definition of `PatchAsync` method at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.patchasync?view=netcore-3.0#System_Net_Http_HttpClient_PatchAsync_System_String_System_Net_Http_HttpContent_). Also, I've just fixed a small error in my posted code.

Comment: How can I pass `APIURL` ? I changed the code as `string serviceUrl = string.Format("{0}/notification/updateMessageTemplate/{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LtApiUrl"], templateID);`  but still have error (`does not contain a definition for 'PatchAsync' and no accessible extension method 'PatchAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpClient'`)

Comment: Have you added required namespaces in your code which is `System.Net.Http` and `System.Net`?

Comment: I'm using `using System.Net.Http;` please see this image my code not suggest `PatchAsync`  https://i.imgur.com/3HbvVAl.png

Comment: Are you using .NetCore? If no, then use the SendAsync method. Checked [this] fiddle which shows both `SendAsync` and `PostAsync` implementation example.

Comment: The added fiddle https://dotnetfiddle.net/WY4C4o is for .Net core only. Check the fiddle please

Comment: Not working sir, Patch not showing. But only have put. I changed the code to `PUT`. its also showing errors

Comment: Then use SendAsync method